# Jupyter notebook magic command - use %who DataFrame to get list of DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I can print all interactive variables, with some minimal formatting using `%who`.

If I only want defined DataFrames, `%who DataFrame` works great.

**Is there a way to send the output of `%who DataFrame` to a list?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [`%who_ls`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-who_ls) is what you're looking for:

> Return a sorted list of all interactive variables. 
>   If arguments are given, only variables of types matching these arguments are returned.

Example use -

```
In [1]: x, y, z = 1, 1, 1

In [2]: ints = %who_ls int

In [3]: print(ints)
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use this command to get the output of who into a variable:

```
df_list = %who_ls DataFrame
```